# Alinear input dinámicos

Tags: input

acudo a usted porque tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un boton dinamico que me crea 3 inputs pero no hay caso que aparezcan un al lado del otro, aparecen los 3 montados.

Es un tema de estetica pero cuando se aumentan queda todo muy engorroso

codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".btn-secondary"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>\
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="coordenadas" placeholder="Direccion" name="mytext[]"/>\
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="coordenadas" placeholder="Direccion" name="mytext[]"/>\
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="coordenadas" placeholder="Direccion" name="mytext[]"/>\
            <a href="#" class="remove_field">Eliminar</a>\
            </div>'); //add input box




        }
    });


    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

codigo HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <button class="btn-secondary">Agregar sucursales</button> 
                                                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Que me falta? además después debo capturar los datos , pero voy por etapas.. j
gracias.